# Buy domain without static, public IP address

Tags: domains, dns, dns-servers, dynamic-dns

I'm about to buy a domain, just for a personal website, where the availability is not that crucial at all.

As of now, I don't have a static, public IP.

My question is, if I could buy the domain (e.g. `example.com`) and configure it to point to my DynDNS (or equivalent services) domain name (e.g. `mocksite.dyndnsprov.com`), ultimately allowing someone to visit `example.com`, without having the DynDNS name apparent in the browser?

For instance, with the scenario in place, when someone enters `example.com` in their browser, the domain resolves to `mocksite.dyndnsprov.com`, which again resolves to my current public home IP address. The user is shown the content hosted on my home server and is displayed the `example.com` address in the address bar of his browser.

Comment: Why not just use `example.com` that resolves to the IP address of your home server? i.e http://dyn.com/remote-access/ ~ If you go down the redirect route from domain to domain, only the resulting domain will be indexed by search engines... meaning your custom domain is pointless.

Comment: I don't want to use a paid service like dyn and I do not care about search engine indexing at all. In the end this is more or less just a trial for myself to get to learn how free dynamic DNS services and domain purchasing/managing. With the neat side-effect that I have access to my home server with a neat domain name.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you do or do not want to use such a service... you need to since its a DNS limitation and the only thing that can be done is that you redirect from one to another, but the later domain name will appear in your address bar... not your custom domain. There's a reason why they charge for such a service... if it could be done by other means then why would they be selling such a service? huh? you can redirect it or make a virtual domain using your operating system host file that maps your external IP to a `X.com`, you wouldn't even need to purchase X.

Comment: Related question: [I registered a domain name — how can I point it to my DynDNS host?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27012/i-registered-a-domain-name-how-can-i-point-it-to-my-dyndns-host)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can do this for the apex (bare) domain (unless your DNS provider specifically supports this), however, you could create a `CNAME` record for a subdomain that points to your DynDNS domain name.

```
home.example.com CNAME mocksite.dyndnsprov.com
```

Your DynDNS domain "contains" an `A` record that points to your (dynamic) IP address (which is automatically updated using some software on the client).

So, `http://home.example.com` will now direct traffic to your home server. (You still need to configure your home network and server to accept/route such requests.)

Answer (score 3):

There are other services besides DynDNS that will host your DNS and "point" it to your dynamic IP address. (Example: [EntryDNS](https://entrydns.net/)) In other words, you can point "example.com" to your dynamic IP address without doing any kind of "translation" or redirection, etc. 
A small script on your server can keep the IP address updated on a schedule (every 15 minutes, for example) should it change.

I have used both DynDNS and EntryDNS, and EntryDNS offers this service and seems to be much more reliable. If I remember correctly it only requires a $12 lifetime registration fee.